# Playback of FFMPEG Audio Using NAudio Has Lots of Noise

Tags: c#, c++, audio, ffmpeg, naudio

I have a video that I'm trying to play back using the FFMPEG framework, and NAudio to playback the audio frames. The video plays back just fine, but when I play back the audio using a BufferedWaveProvider while the underlying audio sounds correct, it has a ton of static/noise. What's important to note in the attached code is when the events fire off from the managed C++ class, a C# class receives the event and then grabs the latest relevant AVFrame data. This works flawlessly for video, but like I said, when I try to play back the audio I have a bunch of noise. For now I've hardcoded the NAudio WaveFormat settings, but they should match the video's audio.

```
    ///////////////////////// C# /////////////////////////////

    // Gets the size of the data from the audio AVFrame (audioFrame->linesize[0])
    int size = _Decoder.GetAVAudioFrameSize();

    if (!once)
    {
        managedArray = new byte[size];
        once = true;
    }

    // Gets the data array from the audio AVFrame
    IntPtr data = _Decoder.GetAVAudioFrameData();

    Marshal.Copy(data, managedArray, 0, size);

    if (_waveProvider == null)
    {
        _waveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2));
        _waveOut.NumberOfBuffers = 2;
        _waveOut.DesiredLatency = 300;
        _waveOut.Init(_waveProvider);
        _waveOut.Play();
    }

    _waveProvider.AddSamples(managedArray, 0, size);


    //////////////////////// Managed C++ /////////////////////////
    while (_shouldRead)
    {
        // if we're not initialized, sleep
        if (!_initialized || !_FFMpegObject->AVFormatContextReady())
        {
            Thread::Sleep(READ_INIT_WAIT_TIME);
        }
        else if (_sequentialFailedReadCount > MAX_SEQUENTIAL_READ_FAILS)
        {
            // we've failed a lot and probably lost the stream, try to reconnect.
            _sequentialFailedReadCount = 0;
            _initialized = false;
            StartInitThread();
            Thread::Sleep(READ_INIT_WAIT_TIME << 1);
        }
        else // otherwise, try reading one AV packet 
        {
            if (_FFMpegObject->AVReadFrame())
            {
                if (_FFMpegObject->GetAVPacketStreamIndex() == _videoStreamIndex)
                {
                    _sequentialFailedReadCount = 0;

                    // decode the video packet
                    _frameLock->WaitOne();
                    frameFinished = _FFMpegObject->AVCodecDecodeVideo2();
                    _frameLock->ReleaseMutex();

                    if (frameFinished)
                    {
                        _framesDecoded++;

                        if (!_isPaused) // If paused and AFAP playback, just don't call the callback
                        {
                            FrameFinished(this, EventArgs::Empty);

                            Thread::Sleep((int)(1000 / (GetFrameRate() * _speed)));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (_FFMpegObject->GetAVPacketStreamIndex() == _audioStreamIndex)
                {
                    // decode the audio packet.
                    _frameLock->WaitOne();
                    audioFrameFinished = _FFMpegObject->AVCodecDecodeAudio4();
                    _frameLock->ReleaseMutex();

                    if (audioFrameFinished)
                    {
                        if (!_isPaused) // If paused and AFAP playback, just don't call the callback
                        {
                            // Fire the event - leaving it up to video to do the sleeps -- not sure if that will work or not
                            AudioFrameFinished(this, EventArgs::Empty);
                        }
                    }
                }

                _FFMpegObject->AVFreeFramePacket();

            }
            else // failed to read an AV packet
            {
                _sequentialFailedReadCount++;
                _failedReadCount++;
                Thread::Sleep(READ_FAILED_WAIT_TIME);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: a good way of debugging these sorts of issues is to record the audio output and compare the waveform with the correct waveforms with a tool like audacity. the difference may lead you towards the cause

Comment: I'm just curious, what should I be looking for exactly? One is going to be the proper audio, the other will be the proper audio with a bunch of noise. Are there certain cues that will point to one issue or another?

Comment: gaps in the waveform would indicate buffers being too big and not filled, discontinuities would indicate buffers either being too small or some buffers being dropped. you might have a signed/unsigned mismatch which would make the bottom half of the waveform distorted

Comment: you could always post a screenshot if you get stuck

Comment: Thanks, I'll update when able - I've temporarily moved on, but will come back to this in the next couple of days.

Comment: Digging into this a bit more, it seems to be an MP4 issue. If I convert my video to an MPEG there is no static in the audio - it's perfectly clear. This isn't really a solution for me since MPEGs are way too big, but maybe it'll help point to an issue people have run into in the past. I'm running a pretty old version of FFMPEG (2.8 instead of 4.0.2), so I'm going to try updating to the new version as well.